# Give common missing argument in functional

Tags: r, functional-programming, eval

I have a bunch of little functions that generate random strings similar to `rnorm` or `sample`.  These functions all have common arguments, for the sake of simplicity let's say one common argument is `n`.  I'd like to make a larger function (functional) that takes the `n` as and argument plus `...` that can be any of the little functions.  This meta function evaluates the little functions with the set`n` if they have this argument.  here's an example:

**## LITTLE FUNCTIONS**

```
fun1 <- function(n, x = 1:10) sample(x, n, TRUE)
fun2 <- function(n, x = LETTERS) sample(x, n, TRUE)
fun3 <- function(n, x = 50) rnorm(n, x)
fun4 <- function(n, x = 100, y = 10) rnorm(n, x, y)
```

**FUNCTIONAL (META FUNCTION)**

```
combiner <- function(n, ...){

## Where the magic needs to happen.  Set n for `fun1` `fun2` and `fun4`
## evaluate all these functions

}

## Here we pass `n = 6`
combiner(
    6,
    fun1(),
    fun2,
    rnorm(),
    fun4(y=8)
)
```

I'd like it to evaluate functions even if they're missing `()` as Is the case with `fun2` above but this is more of a nicety.  I think this is possible because the **magrittr** pipes can do this.

**## DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
list(
    fun1(6),
    fun2(6),
    rnorm(6),
    fun4(6, y=8)
)


## OUTPUT IS SEED DEPENDANT
## [[1]]
## [1] 2 1 6 6 1 1
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "V" "Z" "A" "F" "F" "G"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] -0.91932716 -0.05833169  1.75440750  2.19959565 -0.11145315  1.32216601
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 107.48747  89.55798  93.15771 111.32380 100.82104 104.07829
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach this:

```
combiner <- function(n, ...) {
    ## Capture the unevaluated calls and symbols passed via ...
    ll <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
    ## Process each one in turn
    lapply(ll, FUN = function(X) {
        ## Turn any symbols/names into calls
        if(is.name(X)) X <- as.call(list(X))
        ## Add/replace an argument named n
        X$n <- n
        ## Evaluate the fixed up call
        eval(X)
    })
}

combiner(6, fun1(), fun2, rnorm(), fun4(y=8))
# [[1]]
# [1] 3 8 9 7 4 7
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Z" "M" "U" "A" "Z" "U"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  0.6100340 -1.0323017 -0.6895327  1.2534378 -0.3513120  0.3116020
#  
# [[4]]
# [1] 112.31979  91.96595  79.11932 108.30020 107.16828  89.46137
```

Comment: I was messing every which way but never got close to that.I've never used `as.call` before.  Thank you.